# Why this error: "cannot create directory `foo': Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, group

I get this error when I try creating a directory:

```
[rex <03:57 PM> /var/tmp/pb82]$  mkdir foo
mkdir: cannot create directory `foo': Permission denied
```

But doesn't the following output indicate that I should be able to create directories there since I am a member of the www-data group to which that directory belongs?

```
[rex <03:57 PM> /var/tmp/pb82]$  ls -l ..
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 5 root www-data 4096 Aug  7 15:32 jinfo
drwxrwxr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Aug  7 20:43 pb82
[rex <03:58 PM> /var/tmp/pb82]$  whoami
rex
[rex <03:58 PM> /var/tmp/pb82]$  groups rex
users www-data
```

Edit: in response to @UlrichDangel:

```
[rex <04:08 PM> /var/tmp/pb82/jinfo]$  id
uid=1008(rex) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably added yourself to the `www-data` group and didn't relogin afterwards.  To change your group membership you can use

```
sg www-data
```

to get a new shell with the appropriate permissions.

groups will return the data from the database and not your effective permissions - from man groups:

> Print  group  memberships for each USERNAME or, if no
>   USERNAME is specified, for the current process (which may differ if the groups database has changed).